# AVX2: Is there a way to implement _mm256_mul_epi8 function for a constant power of 2?

Tags: c++, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I would like to implement the following operation on 8 bit elements:

`_a = _b * 8 + _c`

with vectors. For the plus there is obviously `_mm256_add_epi8` but i was not able to find a `_mm256_mul_epi8` or something to multiply with 8 bit elements. I also tried to find a function to left shift by 3, but no luck.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What shall happen for too large values? Saturation/wrap-around/undefined behavior? Are `b` and `c` signed or unsigned?

Comment: @chtz It is unsigned and also, the max value inside `_b` is 7, so shifting left by 3 should not create an overflow. So everything should be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with only add:

```
__m256i _b2 = _mm256_add_epi8(_b,_b);
__m256i _b4 = _mm256_add_epi8(_b2,_b2);
__m256i _b8 = _mm256_add_epi8(_b4,_b4);
__m256i _a = _mm256_add_epi8(_b8,_c);
```

You can also do this with any shift, if you mask out high bits of each byte to emulate shifting out:

```
// not needed if _b values are smaller than 32
__m256i _b_low = _mm256_and_si256(_b,_mm256_set1_epi8(0x1F));

__m256i _b8 = _mm256_slli_epi32(_b_low,3);
__m256i _a = _mm256_add_epi8(_b8,_c);
```

Comment: N.B: If `b` is known to be smaller than `32` you don't need the bitmask operation.